# Catch InvalidOperationException with empty structure

Tags: c#, exception, invalidoperationexception

I am trying to catch the `InvalidOperationException` that can sometimes occur when declaring variables. The following code doesn't work however. Probably because I don't really know how you catch an exception.

```
public override void Download()
{
    try
    {                                           
        var t = (ForumThread)Globals.Db.Thread.Get(_extIdForumThread, _idF);            
        try
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException exception)
        {
            return;
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Any help at all would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to throw the exception yourself. Just have:

```
    try
    {                                           
        var t = (ForumThread)Globals.Db.Thread.Get(_extIdForumThread, _idF);
    }
    catch (InvalidOperationException exception)
    {
        // Error logging, post processing etc.
        return;
    }
```

You shouldn't really be catching the general exception either unless you have a really good reason to - i.e. your application cannot crash, but if you do you need to be able to recover from it.

Comment: Thank you very much. That solves my question. But within my project I then get the problem that I cannot compile the project because functions are using the variable t and when it is declared in try catch and I get "The name 't' doesnt exist in the current context." How can I get around that?

Comment: @AndréHegge - if you want to use the variable `t` outside the `try` then you need to declare it outside the `try`. Though it might not be sensible to try to reference it in the exception handler as it could well be unset or contain wrong values.